# Binding Xceed WPF MaskedTextBox to an integer

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, maskedtextbox, xceed

I know something like this has been asked before, but I just can't get it to work. I have a masked textbox like this:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox IncludeLiteralsInValue="False" Mask="000-00-0000"
  TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SomeInteger,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

And, you guessed it, I need to bind it to an `int` property but I keep getting a parsing exception because it seems to be trying to store the dashes as well. No matter what I do, the masked text box is storing the mask as well, and I can clearly see that by changing my property to string.
The problem is, I'm working with someone else's code, and I'm not allowed to change the model of the application, not even the data types. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance
**EDIT:** I never figured out the way to do this, so I created another intermediate property that stores the string and updates the int as necessary, and bound that to the textbox.

Comment: Did you try something like this `ValueDataType="{x:Type s:Int32}"`